# using columns for comparisons KQL

Tags: kql

The following works ...

```
datatable(RawData:string, Comparison:string) [
"Everyone is happy but me", "Everyone is happy"
]
| where RawData contains Comparison
```

Except when there is a character such as \ in either the comparison or the rawdata. Is there a way to nullify this?

```
 datatable(RawData:string, Comparison:string) [
    "\Everyone is happy but me", "\Everyone is happy"
    ]
    | where RawData contains Comparison
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [verbatim string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/string#verbatim-string-literals)

```
datatable(RawData:string, Comparison:string) [
    @"\Everyone is happy but me", @"\Everyone is happy"
    ]
    | where RawData contains Comparison
```

| RawData | Comparison |
| --- | --- |
| \Everyone is happy but me | \Everyone is happy |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA0tJLAHCpJxUjaDEchcg06q4pCgzL11HwTk/tyCxKLM4Pw8qpKkQzculAAQOSjGuZalFlfl5qQqZxQoZiQUFlQpJpSUKualKOlhllSAaYyFUjUJ5RmpRqgLURoXk/LySxMy8YiQrAbb9FfaXAAAA)

Or you can use [double-escaping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/string#string-literals)

> The backslash () character indicates escaping. The backslash is used
> to escape the enclosing quote characters, tab characters (\t), newline
> characters (\n), **and itself (\\)**.

```
datatable(RawData:string, Comparison:string) [
    "\\Everyone is happy but me", "\\Everyone is happy"
    ]
    | where RawData contains Comparison
```

| RawData | Comparison |
| --- | --- |
| \Everyone is happy but me | \Everyone is happy |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA0tJLAHCpJxUjaDEchcg06q4pCgzL11HwTk/tyCxKLM4Pw8qpKkQzculAARKMTGuZalFlfl5qQqZxQoZiQUFlQpJpSUKualKOlhllSAaYyFUjUJ5RmpRqgLURoXk/LySxMy8YiQrAaSMH9iXAAAA)

Comment: Is there a way I can convert a field to a verbatim literal?

Comment: That's contradicting to the definition of literal. What is the exact challenge you're facing?

Comment: ill see if i can formulate a better worded question :))